# React native app building but not opening on Android 10 (opens on Android 13)

Tags: android, react-native

My current version of React Native is `"react-native": "0.71.7"`

The app is successfully building and opening on my Android emulator that has Android API 33 installed, using the below commands:

`npx react-native start`
`npx react-native run-android`

But when I test the app on the same emulator with Android 10 API 29 installed - the app builds successfully and installs on the emulator however, the app does not open. When I try open the app manually (by clicking the icon) I get the "App keeps stopping" popup with App Info and Close buttons, but no further logs in the console or anything.

It also does not look like it is connecting to the metro server as there are no logs or indexing (which I get when I run the app on the same Emulator with Android API 33 installed)

I have spent days tinkering with my `android/app/build.gradle` (in an attempt to resolve the issue)

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"
apply plugin: "com.facebook.react"

apply from: project(':react-native-config').projectDir.getPath() + "/dotenv.gradle"


import com.android.build.OutputFile


project.ext.react = [
    enableHermes: true,  // clean and rebuild if changing
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

/**
 * Set this to true to create two separate APKs instead of one:
 *   - An APK that only works on ARM devices
 *   - An APK that only works on x86 devices
 * The advantage is the size of the APK is reduced by about 4MB.
 * Upload all the APKs to the Play Store and people will download
 * the correct one based on the CPU architecture of their device.
 */
def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

/**
 * Run Proguard to shrink the Java bytecode in release builds.
 */
def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

/**
 * The preferred build flavor of JavaScriptCore.
 *
 * For example, to use the international variant, you can use:
 * `def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'`
 *
 * The international variant includes ICU i18n library and necessary data
 * allowing to use e.g. `Date.toLocaleString` and `String.localeCompare` that
 * give correct results when using with locales other than en-US.  Note that
 * this variant is about 6MiB larger per architecture than default.
 */
def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

/**
 * Whether to enable the Hermes VM.
 *
 * This should be set on project.ext.react and that value will be read here. If it is not set
 * on project.ext.react, JavaScript will not be compiled to Hermes Bytecode
 * and the benefits of using Hermes will therefore be sharply reduced.
 */
def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", false);

/**
 * Private function to get the list of Native Architectures you want to build.
 * This reads the value from reactNativeArchitectures in your gradle.properties
 * file and works together with the --active-arch-only flag of react-native run-android.
 */
def reactNativeArchitectures() {
    def value = project.getProperties().get("reactNativeArchitectures")
    return value ? value.split(",") : ["armeabi-v7a", "x86", "x86_64", "arm64-v8a"]
}


android {

    ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion

    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.centreofexcellence.app"
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 200
        versionName "1.2.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        missingDimensionStrategy ('store', 'play' )

        // added as part of react-native-image-crop-picker dependency installation
        // Refer: https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker#android
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
        buildConfigField "boolean", "IS_NEW_ARCHITECTURE_ENABLED", isNewArchitectureEnabled().toString()
    }
    packagingOptions {
        pickFirst '**/libjsc.so'
        pickFirst '**/libc++_shared.so'
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false  // If true, also generate a universal APK
            include (*reactNativeArchitectures())
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
                storeFile file('debug.keystore')
                storePassword 'android'
                keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
                keyPassword 'android'
        }

        release {
            storeFile file('coe-release-upload-key.keystore')
            storePassword ''
            keyAlias 'coe-release-upload-key-alias'
            keyPassword ''
        }
 }


    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
        release {
            // Caution! In production, you need to generate your own keystore file.
            // see https://reactnative.dev/docs/signed-apk-android.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            minifyEnabled enableProguardInReleaseBuilds
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"), "proguard-rules.pro"
        }
    }

    // applicationVariants are e.g. debug, release
    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            // For each separate APK per architecture, set a unique version code as described here:
            // https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits.html
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) {  // null for the universal-debug, universal-release variants
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        defaultConfig.versionCode * 1000 + versionCodes.get(abi)
            }

        }
    }
}

dependencies {

     constraints {
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.8.0") {
            because("kotlin-stdlib-jdk7 is now a part of kotlin-stdlib")
        }
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.8.0") {
            because("kotlin-stdlib-jdk8 is now a part of kotlin-stdlib")
        }
    }

    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0"
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation "org.webkit:android-jsc:+"

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
      exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
        exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    }

   if (hermesEnabled.toBoolean()) {
        implementation("com.facebook.react:hermes-android")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }
}

// Run this once to be able to run the application with BUCK
// puts all compile dependencies into folder libs for BUCK to use
task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.implementation
    into 'libs'
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)

// @react-native-firebase/app
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

// react-native-vector-icons
apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"

def isNewArchitectureEnabled() {
    // To opt-in for the New Architecture, you can either:
    // - Set `newArchEnabled` to true inside the `gradle.properties` file
    // - Invoke gradle with `-newArchEnabled=true`
    // - Set an environment variable `ORG_GRADLE_PROJECT_newArchEnabled=true`
    return project.hasProperty("newArchEnabled") && project.newArchEnabled == "true"
}
```

My `android/build.gradle` looks as follows

```
import org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.condition.Os

// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "31.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 28
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 31
        googlePlayServicesAuthVersion = "16.0.1"
        kotlinVersion = '1.6.20'

        if (System.properties['os.arch'] == "aarch64") {
            // For M1 Users we need to use the NDK 24 which added support for aarch64
            ndkVersion = "24.0.8215888"
        } else {
            // Otherwise we default to the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
            ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
        }
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
       classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.4.2')
       classpath('com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin')
       classpath('de.undercouch:gradle-download-task:5.0.1')
       classpath("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.6.20")
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            // All of React Native (JS, Obj-C sources, Android binaries) is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            // Android JSC is installed from npm
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
        mavenCentral {
            // We don't want to fetch react-native from Maven Central as there are
            // older versions over there.
            content {
                excludeGroup "com.facebook.react"
            }
        }
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
        maven { url "$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android" }

        // added as part of react-native-image-crop-picker dependency installation
        // Refer: https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker#android
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }

        // added as part of react-native-image-crop-picker dependency installation
        // Refer: https://github.com/ivpusic/react-native-image-crop-picker#android
        maven { url "https://www.jitpack.io" }
    }

    // added as part of react-native-reanimated v1 fix https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-reanimated/issues/3242#issuecomment-1145423942
    subprojects { subproject ->
            if(project['name'] == 'react-native-reanimated'){
                project.configurations { compile { } }
            }
    }

}
```

package.json:

```
{
    "name": "coe",
    "version": "1.1.1",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "android": "react-native run-android",
        "ios": "react-native run-ios",
        "start": "react-native start",
        "test": "jest",
        "lint": "eslint . --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx",
        "format": "prettier --check ./src",
        "postversion": "react-native-version --never-amend",
        "bump-version": "yarn version --no-git-tag-version",
        "bump-android-build": "react-native-version --skip-tag -b --target android",
        "bump-ios-build": "react-native-version --skip-tag -b --target ios",
        "update-ios-jsbundle": "npx react-native bundle --minify --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ./ios/CoE/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ./ios/CoE",
        "postinstall": "patch-package"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@invertase/react-native-apple-authentication": "^2.1.0",
        "@native-html/table-plugin": "^5.3.0",
        "@native-html/transient-render-engine": "^11.2.3",
        "@react-native-community/checkbox": "^0.5.8",
        "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^6.4.2",
        "@react-native-community/google-signin": "^5.0.0",
        "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
        "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^9.0.0",
        "@react-native-community/slider": "^4.0.3",
        "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^17.0.0",
        "@react-native-firebase/app": "^17.0.0",
        "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^17.0.0",
        "@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^17.0.0",
        "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^17.0.0",
        "@react-native-firebase/remote-config": "^17.0.0",
        "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.2",
        "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.12.3",
        "@react-navigation/native": "^5.8.10",
        "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.12.8",
        "@sentry/react-native": "^2.4.3",
        "axios": "^0.21.1",
        "currency-symbol-map": "^5.0.1",
        "deprecated-react-native-prop-types": "^4.0.0",
        "form-data": "^4.0.0",
        "i18n-js": "^3.7.1",
        "immer": "^9.0.21",
        "jsc-android": "^250231.0.0",
        "libphonenumber-js": "^1.10.26",
        "lodash": "^4.17.21",
        "moment": "^2.29.4",
        "moment-timezone": "^0.5.43",
        "patch-package": "^6.5.1",
        "postinstall-postinstall": "^2.1.0",
        "react": "18.2.0",
        "react-native": "0.71.7",
        "react-native-airplay-menu": "^1.0.13",
        "react-native-bluetooth-classic": "^1.60.0-rc.26",
        "react-native-circular-progress": "^1.3.8",
        "react-native-collapsible": "^1.6.1",
        "react-native-config": "^1.5.0",
        "react-native-country-picker-modal": "^2.0.0",
        "react-native-device-info": "^10.6.0",
        "react-native-document-picker": "^8.2.0",
        "react-native-dropdown-picker": "^5.4.6",
        "react-native-easy-toast": "^2.3.0",
        "react-native-fast-image": "^8.6.3",
        "react-native-fbsdk-next": "^11.1.0",
        "react-native-flags-typescript": "^1.0.1",
        "react-native-fs": "^2.18.0",
        "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.9.0",
        "react-native-iap": "^9.0.4",
        "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.38.0",
        "react-native-inappbrowser-reborn": "^3.7.0",
        "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
        "react-native-keychain": "^8.1.1",
        "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.6.2",
        "react-native-localize": "^2.2.6",
        "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^15.0.0",
        "react-native-new-snap-carousel": "^3.9.3",
        "react-native-pell-rich-editor": "^1.8.9",
        "react-native-popover-view": "^5.0.0",
        "react-native-progress": "^5.0.0",
        "react-native-reanimated": "^1.13.4",
        "react-native-render-html": "^6.1.0",
        "react-native-responsive-screen": "^1.4.2",
        "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.4.1",
        "react-native-screens": "2.15.0",
        "react-native-snackbar": "2.4.0",
        "react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.9.1",
        "react-native-splash-screen": "^3.3.0",
        "react-native-svg": "^13.7.0",
        "react-native-track-player": "^2.1.4",
        "react-native-url-polyfill": "^1.3.0",
        "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.2.0",
        "react-native-webview": "^11.26.1",
        "react-redux": "^7.2.1",
        "react-yup": "^1.21.0",
        "redux": "^4.0.5",
        "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
        "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
        "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.13.0-beta.2",
        "rn-range-slider": "^2.0.4",
        "yup": "^0.32.9",
        "yup-phone": "^1.2.19"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
        "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
        "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^3.2.0",
        "@rnx-kit/align-deps": "^2.1.3",
        "@types/i18n-js": "^3.0.3",
        "@types/jest": "^25.2.3",
        "@types/react-native": "^0.63.43",
        "@types/react-native-snap-carousel": "^3.8.2",
        "@types/react-native-vector-icons": "^6.4.6",
        "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.15",
        "@types/react-test-renderer": "^16.9.4",
        "@types/redux-logger": "^3.0.8",
        "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.12.0",
        "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.12.0",
        "babel-jest": "^25.1.0",
        "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.1.0",
        "eslint": "^7.17.0",
        "eslint-config-airbnb": "^18.2.0",
        "eslint-import-resolver-typescript": "^2.3.0",
        "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.0",
        "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.3.1",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.1",
        "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.22.0",
        "eslint-plugin-react-hooks": "^4.1.0",
        "jest": "^26.6.3",
        "jetifier": "^2.0.0",
        "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.73.9",
        "prettier": "^2.2.1",
        "react-native-version": "^4.0.0",
        "react-test-renderer": "17.0.1",
        "typescript": "^3.9.10"
    },
    "rnpm": {
        "assets": [
            "./assests/fonts/"
        ]
    },
    "jest": {
        "preset": "react-native",
        "moduleFileExtensions": [
            "ts",
            "tsx",
            "js",
            "jsx",
            "json",
            "node"
        ]
    }
}
```

I also tried building a apk and installing it on a real device with Android 10 installed and I am experiencing the same issue. I have tested the same apk on a real device with Android 13 installed and again, the opens and works fine.

At this point I am all out of ideas, atleast if I was getting a error or some sort of log, I could work with that.

The problem on Android 10 is happening for both debug and release builds of the app

Please let me know if I need to include any additional information

I have tried running the app on both a emulator and real device with Android 13 installed, the app works and opens as expected.

I have tried running the app on both a emulator and real device with Android 10 installed, the app installs but does not open. It also does not appear to be connecting to the debugger/console.

Comment: Run the app in Android-13 with debugger attached and see if any error/warning present in console.

Comment: Okay thanks, there are several warnings, why would it work on Android 13 and just not even open or connect to debugger on android 10 though?

Comment: i have the same issue 
did find any solutions ?

Comment: Nope, been struggling for days. Please let me know if you find any solutions & I will do the same.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem (app works on all Android versions above 10, but not on version 10).
I found an error related to loading Flipper using Android Studio's Logcat, and solved it simply by setting Flipper version to 0.105.0 in graddle.properties.
This simple change made it works on all Android versions.

Answer (score -1):

Seems like I am facing the same issue. In my case, the not working project is almost 1 year old. It was working fine about 2 weeks back. Now it is not working on Android 10 devices (Redmi Note 9 pro).

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "31.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 31
        targetSdkVersion = 31

        if (System.properties['os.arch'] == "aarch64") {
            // For M1 Users we need to use the NDK 24 which added support for aarch64
            ndkVersion = "24.0.8215888"
        } else {
            // Otherwise we default to the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
            ndkVersion = "21.4.7075529"
        }
        kotlin_version = '1.6.10'
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0")
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.13'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a place for providing an answer.
If you have a question, please consider creating a new post, and then add a link to that post in the comments to this question.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34480500)